# Expected instance props to match memoized props in React 16

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

I am upgrading from `react` version `15` to `16` (16.6.1) and I am seeing this warning a bunch in the console, should I be worried?

`Warning: Expected instance props to match memoized props before componentDidUpdate. This is likely due to a bug in React. Please file an issue.`

I can't really file an issue because I can't pinpoint it and it's not my code to share. I can't find anything online about this issue.

Should I be worried? Should I just let it slip?

Comment: Can you post some sample code? Or at least provide an example that triggers the same warning.

Comment: @mattcarlotta I can I can reproducing warning, [see my comment on github issues](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14224)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at a reproducing case in [this issue report](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14224#issuecomment-440010967), this happens because a particular library (in that example, `react-css-modules`) overwrites the `this.props` object in your React component.

This has never been supported and can lead to other issues. If you must rely on this, a possible workaround is described [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14224#issuecomment-440011268).

Answer (score 0):

it took me days to solved. The issue was this.state was my local variable ref for address field.

ref={ref => (this.state = ref)} // error line